# Implement Support Vector machine (SVM) in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm

i am trying to use support vector machine with linear kernel to classify x1 and x2 based on y. My code ran but I get a warning saying `WARNING: reaching max number of iterations` Also when I try to plot my predictions I get this `Error in c("red", "blue")[y.hat + 1] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts` I don't know why. Here is the data + code

```
library(e1071)

set.seed(10)

x1 <- runif(500) - 0.5

x2 <- runif(500) - 0.5

y <- ifelse(x1 ^ 2 - x2 ^ 2 > 0, 1, 0)

dat <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)

fit.svm <- svm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, kernel = "linear", cost = 1e8)

y.hat <- predict(fit1.svm, dat)

plot(x1,x2,col = c("red","blue")[y.hat + 1])
```

Comment: It comes from `library(e1071)` good catch I am gonna edit my question

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Why have you manually set the `cost` argument to such a large number? Does the model work when the cost is 1, the default?

Comment: Beautiful catch I tried with the default cost argument and everything works perfectly thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yea it works perfectly with default cost

Comment: Hello everything looks fine.the variable defined in predict() is fit1.svm and not fit.svm and 1000 iterations does work but 1e8 iterations doesn't work as we don't have that many combinations in the data and will be recursive

Comment: @DineshKumar    This time when I run logistic regression on the same data set and I plot the prediction, I only get points from x2 something must be wrong, here is what I attempted                                      `#Logistic Regression
fit.glm <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, family = "binomial")

y.hat.3 <- predict(fit.glm,dat)

plot(x1,x2,col = c("red","blue")[y.hat.3 + 1])`